# Unique textbox required issue with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, each

I have a small form with three fields that are all required.

```
<div class="span5 offset3 well">
  <legend>To begin, please enter the info below</legend>
  <div class="alert alert-error hide" id="error">
    <span>Incorrect Username or Password!</span>
  </div>
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="POST" name="check_form" id="check_form">
    <p>
      <label>Student ID</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtEmplid" placeholder="Student ID" name="txtEmplid" class="span5">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Email address</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" class="span5">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>OR</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>DOB</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" id="dob" name="dob" class="span5">
    </p>
    <button type="submit" id="doCheck" name="doCheck" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="form-submit" name="form-submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Originally, this was fine. However, now I need to modify it so that the user is required to enter the ID and at least one of the other two. For example. Id and DOB are filled out, but Email is blank.

Initially, I wrote a small jQuery function that I used to change the background color of any text box that was empty to red. Here is that code:

```
function doFieldEmpty(input) {

    var ic = 0;
    var $i = input;

    $i.each(function( index, value ) {

        // if empty, add red background class
        if ($(this).val() == '') {

            $(this).addClass('inputerror')
                   .attr('placeholder', 'Required')
                   .val(index);
        } else {

            $(this).removeClass('inputerror');

        }
    });
}
```

I call it using this.

```
doFieldEmpty($("#studentid, #email, #dob"));
```

Since this code already loops through the jQuery object, I'm a bit hesitant to write another function that does what I want.

So my question is, how can I modify this function that it does both.

I hope I've explained in enough detail for what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the (representative) HTML that this jQuery should work with?

Comment: Added form HTML to main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really just have 3 fields and are simply checking for the condition you mention, you are better off replacing your existing code with a basic, 2-condition check:

```
function validateFields() {
    $('input').removeClass('inputerror');

    // Check if ID is blank
    if( $('#studentid').val() === '') {
        $('#studentid').addClass('inputerror');
    }

    // Check if both email and dob are blank
    if( $('#email').val() === '' && $('#dob').val() === '' ) {
         $('#email, #dob').addClass('inputerror');   
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3X86W/

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow your advice and keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

What about passing an additional parameter, minimumRequired, and increment the count in the for each loop.

```
function doFieldEmpty(input, minimumRequired) {

var ic = 0;
var $i = input;
var emptyCount = 0;

$i.each(function( index, value ) {

    // if empty, add red background class
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        emptyCount++;
        if(emptyCount >= minimumRequired){
        $(this).addClass('inputerror')
               .attr('placeholder', 'Required')
               .val(index);
        }
    } else {

        $(this).removeClass('inputerror');

    }
});
}
```